# spike of a crash in iOS 10.2 - _dispatch_call_block_and_release

Tags: crash, ios10.2

We oberserved spike of a crash (libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_call_block_and_release) in iOS 10.2. This crash wasn't new, however, a spike occurred since iOS 10.2 release. Anybody experienced with the same crashes and had found the root cause? Thanks!

```
libobjc.A.dylib in objc_msgSend + 16
libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_client_callout + 12
libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 924
libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_queue_invoke + 648
libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 356
libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 568
libdispatch.dylib in _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
libsystem_pthread.dylib in _pthread_wqthread + 1284
libsystem_pthread.dylib in start_wqthread + 0
```

Comment: Hi did you get any solution for this, me too having same issue

Comment: we did. we found there was an issue in our code and has resolved the issue. however, we are not clear why this only occurs in iOS 10.2 but not in iOS 10.1 and below.

Comment: Yes same was with me.

Comment: Is anyone able to share a solution to this? I've seen similar crashes with 10.2 in the field, but I can't recreate them. Whenever I try and force this condition my block executes without a problem.